# finite objects of $G$-Set.

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

I am self-studying Aluffi Chapter 0. I am stuck on the following problem. Prove that $G$-Set has products and coproducts, and that every finite object of $G$-Set is a coproduct of objects of type $G/H = \{\rm{left} \ \rm{cosets} \ of \ H\}$, where $H$ is subgroup of $G$, and $G$ acts on $G/H$ by left multiplication.

Given $(G,A)$ and $(G,A^{\prime})$. Then $(G,A \times A^{\prime})$ is the product and $(G,A \oplus A^{\prime})$ is coproduct respectively. I am having troubles proving the second assertion. That every finite object of $G$-Set is coproduction of objects.

Comment: Do you know the orbit–stabiliser theorem?

Comment: I am not sure Aluffi covered it by that name. But is it If O is an orbit of the action of a finite group G on a set A, then O is a finite set, and |O| divides |G| ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you have a good idea of how products and coproducts should work, but your notation isn't very explicit. But to double check, if we have two $G$-sets $(\alpha, A)$ and $(\beta, B)$ (using Aluffi's notation) then their product is $A \times B$ equipped with the "diagonal action"

$$(\alpha \times \beta)(g,(a,b)) = (\alpha(g,a), \beta(g,b))$$

and their coproduct is $A+B$ equipped with the action

$$(\alpha + \beta)(g,x) = \begin{cases} \alpha(g,x) & x \in A \\ \beta(g,b) & x \in B \end{cases}$$

I'll leave it to you to check that these really are actions, and they really are products/coproducts.

---

Now for the brunt of your question: Why should every object in $G$-set be a coproduct of objects that look like $G / H$ with the left-multiplication action?

First: it is not just the *finite* objects which have this form. While it turns out $G$-set is a [topos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topos), and thus there *is* a notion of "[finite object](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/finite+object)" it turns out there's a lot of different things one could mean by this (see the linked article for more info), so it's a good thing that it won't matter for us.

Since this exercise is to do with the category of $G$-sets, it makes sense to look at the section right before this exercise ($9.3$ "Transitive Actions and the Category $G$-Set").

One of the first remarks in this section says

> Orbits of an action of a group $G$ on a set $A$ form a partition of $A$; and we have an induced, *transitive* action of $G$ on each orbit. Therefore we can, in a sense, 'understand' all actions if we understand transitive actions. This will be accomplished in a moment, by studying actions related to stabilizers.

Aluffi then goes on to prove the following theorem:

> *Every transitive left-action of $G$ on a nonempty set $A$ is isomorphic to the left-multiplication action of $G$ on $G / H$, for $H =$ the stabilizer of any $a \in A$.*

So informally, Aluffi is telling us that every $G$-set looks like a disjoint union of transitive $G$-sets, and that every transitive $G$-set looks like the left action of $G$ on $G / H$.
The exercise you are working with is supposed to make this intuition precise.

I'll leave the details to you, since this really is a good exercise. But the idea is this:

1. Fix a $G$-set $(\alpha, A)$, and show that $A$ is the disjoint union of its orbits (that is, the coproduct in $\mathsf{Set}$). This basically amounts to showing that "$a_1 \sim a_2$ if and only if they are in the same orbit" is an equivalence relation.
2. Show that for each orbit $O$ we get an action $(\alpha \upharpoonright_O, O)$ by *restricting* $\alpha$ to $O$. Moreover, show that this action is transitive. As a hint for transitivity, recall the *definition* of an orbit. I realize after typing this that this sounds slightly patronizing, but transitivity is the same as "only one orbit", so there's not much more hint I can give, unfortunately.
3. Next, show that $(\alpha, A)$ is the coproduct of all these orbits with their induced actions. That is, $(\alpha, A) \cong \sum_{O \text{ is an orbit}} (\alpha \upharpoonright_O, O)$. Don't think too hard about the isomorphism: the identity map works.
4. By the proposition quoted earlier, each orbit $(\alpha \upharpoonright_O, O)$ is isomorphic to some $G / H_O$ (since the action is transitive). Combining this with your isomorphism from part $3$ will give
   $(\alpha, A) \cong \sum_{O \text{ is an orbit}} G / H_O$, which is exactly what you wanted to show.

Each individual step here follows immediately from understanding what $G$-sets really are, and solving this exercise (ideally getting to a point where this claim is "obvious") will help you get to a point where you really understand $G$-sets. Good luck!

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thanks :). This helps a lot!